# Value set on style.display in unit test is not on the element in implementation

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I understand this is a simplified example, but how come in the test below, the `if` branch is never executed?

`displayValue` is always being set to `inline`, even though in my test I'm setting a value ..

```
it('should store the display value in an attribute', function() {
  var myElement = document.createElement('myElement');
  myElement.style.display = 'hidden';
  myObject.doSomething(myElement);
  expect(myElement.getAttribute('original-display')).to.equal('hidden');
});
```

The implementation is like this ..

```
function doSomething(element) {
  var displayValue = element.style.display !== '' ? element.style.display : 'inline';
  console.log(displayValue); // always prints `inline`
  element.setAttribute('original-display', displayValue);
  element.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `display` attribute of an element will never be an empty string because it always has a default. Also, `hidden` is an invalid value for the `display` attribute, so that never gets set. `hidden` is a value for the `visibility` attribute. So an element can be `display: inline` but also be `visibility: hidden`, for example.

Comment: my bad, forgot `hidden` was for `visibility`